# Unix Shell : Search file and append its last occurence

Tags: shell, unix, search, awk, append

I am trying to search a given text in a file and find its last occurrence index.
The task is to append the searched index in the same file but in a separate column.
I am able to accomplish the task but looking for a more efficient solution.

Following is the detailed description:

names_file.txt

```
tarun trehan
vikram batra
allzhere blog
allzhere android apps
allzhere on facebook
contact updater utility
help me
```

I run the following command to fetch the results in a staging file i.e names_searched.txt

```
grep "n" names_file.txt > names_searched.txt
```

Following is the result:

```
tarun trehan
allzhere android apps
allzhere on facebook
contact updater utility
```

Now, I run the following awk command to extract the last index of "n".

```
cat names_searched.txt | awk -F"n" '{print length($0) - length($NF)}' > namex_srch_idx.txt
```

Following is the result:

```
12
11
11
3
```

Now i paste files to prepare a resultant files i.e.

```
paste names_searched.txt namex_srch_idx.txt > names_result.txt
```

Following is the desired result:

```
tarun trehan    12
allzhere android apps   11
allzhere on facebook    11
contact updater utility 3
```

Is there a work around where we do not need to create the staging files and still achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk` one liner:

```
awk -F"n" '{ len=length($0) - length($NF); if( len > 0 ) print $0,len }'  names_file.txt > names_result.txt
```

Another one `awk` one liner mentioned by **fedorqui**,

```
awk -F"n" 'NF>1{print $0, length($0) - length($NF)}' names_file.txt > names_result.txt
```

Comment: Or even `awk -F"n" 'NF>1{print $0, length($0) - length($NF)}' file`. So that lines without "n" will have NF==1, and hence not printed.

Comment: Thanks all...this worked like a charm. However, i am facing another concern where the names_file.txt has data in the following format : 111|aaa|555|tarun trehan ... i need to search for last occurrence only in the name column and print the index i.e. 111|aaa|555|tarun trehan|12 ... any leads on that ... i tried piping results but didn't get through....

Comment: Try this : `awk -F"n" 'NF>1{n=split($0,lnames," ");print lnames[n], length($0) - length($NF)}'`

Comment: Sat, this gives me an output as : trehan 24 instead of 111|aaa|555|tarun trehan|12 ... i tried this cat names_file.txt | awk -F"|" '{print $4}' | awk -F"n" 'NF>1{print $0 "|" length($0) -length($NF)}' .. but this gives me just tarun trehan|12 ... is there a way i can access the $0 from first awk and search only in the $4 of it ??

Comment: @Allzhere, Use this: `awk -F"|" '$4 ~ /n/ {n=split($4,arr,"n"); print $0"|"length($4) - length(arr[n])}' names_file.txt`

Comment: Thanks Sat... For now i settled with the following: `nawk -F\| -v X="$SRCH_PARAM" -v Y="$SIC_CODE" 'match ($NF, ".*"X) {print $0, RLENGTH-length(X)+1 , Y}' OFS=\| master.txt >> result.txt` .... Appreciate all your help in this regard.